# Print the client pc date and time using php

Tags: php

I am facing the problem. How to print the local machine data and time on my php page using php. I did try a lot but no positive response. If there is possibility to print the local computer data and time then please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you have done? you are on server side code

Comment: You can't. PHP runs on the server, so it never has visibility of the client machine - unless you send it the data via JS,a form, or some other method - in which case it is trivial as you already have it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705067/how-can-i-get-the-users-local-time-instead-of-the-servers-time

Comment: thank you Fluffeh .....for giving me this knowledge

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would do is, fire a call asynchronously from the client, using JavaScript. Say something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="settime.php" id="timeForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="localTime" name="localTime" />
</form>
```

And in the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("localTime").value =
        (new Date()).getDate() + "/" +
        (new Date()).getMonth() + "/" +
        (new Date()).getYear() + " " +
        (new Date()).getHours() + ":" +
        (new Date()).getMinutes() + ":" +
        (new Date()).getSeconds();
document.getElementById("timeForm").submit();
```

In the server side, you need to do something like this:

```
<?php
  $localTime = strtotime($_POST["localTime"]);
  // Do something with PHP
?>
```