# php "file_get_contents()" returns to “failed to open stream:"

Tags: php

I am using codeigniter and I want to get users current date and time.

Getting error `Message: file_get_contents(http://ip-api.com/json/[ip]): failed to open stream: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.`

```
$xipx = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$xdetails = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json/{$xipx}"));
$timex = $xdetails->timezone;

$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone($timex);
$date = new DateTime( "now" , $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: might be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705067/how-can-i-get-the-users-local-time-instead-of-the-servers-time) can help you if you want to use javascript.

Comment: I know but i don't want that.

Comment: depending on your hosting you probably need to allow_url_fopen in php.ini

Comment: Not working. @Thomas

Comment: did you check the content of $xipx ?

Comment: Yes. showing my ip.

Comment: are you sure allow_url_fopen is enabled? this directive can only be set through php.ini. it will not work otherwise. btw, can you access others urls?