# Confused with "how to store local datetime and Timezone using php/Mysql"

Tags: php, mysql

I have read a lot of articles about `best way to store user's datetime`. [Here is a good one](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-time-zones-in-mysql). The article suggests to store datetime in two seperate column one is for UTC datetime and another is for local datetime and another column for the local timezone. If i understood correctly the `local` date time referred to the user's/client's date time and timezone. Now i know i can save the UTC date time using `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`. But how do i save the local datetime and timezone using php? I need a direction here.

Comment: Save the time as a unix timestamp (timezone independent) and then use the proper code to display the time to the user formatted as desired.

Comment: I want to go with the `DATETIME` and how do i store local `DATETIME`  and also the timezone???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be helpful for you
Possible duplicate [get local user time instead of server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705067/how-can-i-get-the-users-local-time-instead-of-the-servers-time) 

 Moreover, you can fetch local date time using **javascript ajax** call to server.