# PHP date() function not giving correct time

Tags: php, date

I am trying to figure out why php date() is giving me the wrong time, setting the actual time back 2 hours.

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>
```

This gives 2011-01-01 03:14:04 instead of 2011-01-01 05:14:04. The hour is decreased by 2.
I have not change my timezone for date() and when users visit the site I want the time to be correct for their timezone also. How can I get this to work using php?

Comment: Where is your server running? What does `echo date_default_timezone_get();` return?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically detect user's current local time with JavaScript or PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863474/automatically-detect-users-current-local-time-with-javascript-or-php)

Answer (score 3):

it is because by default it shows GMT time you can change for your region with following code

```
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");//set you countary name from below timezone list
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());//now it will show "Asia/Bangkok" or your date time
```

List of Supported Timezones
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use either [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or a [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, and the user would have to set their own timezone in an options menu somewhere.

Otherwise, PHP is a server side language and has no idea what time it is on the user's end.

You would have to use a client side language, JavaScript. You could either have it just be static and display the current user system time, or if for whatever reason you needed to get their time into PHP, you could use some AJAX like scripting to have JavaScript send their time into a script when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the the timezone: [date_default_timezone_set](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or via the [ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

Update: you cannot set the correct date for your users. Javascript can handle it but you'd have to rely on the user's system to determine his/her time.

Answer (score 0):

//Change date format

```
$dateInfo = date_parse_from_format('m-d-Y', $data['post_date']);
$unixTimestamp = mktime(
        $dateInfo['hour'], $dateInfo['minute'], $dateInfo['second'],
        $dateInfo['month'], $dateInfo['day'], $dateInfo['year']
    );
$data['post_date']=date('Y-m-d',$unixTimestamp);
```