# Parsing The Twitter API created_at

Tags: php, datetime, twitter

I want to parse the Twitter API `created_at` value(stored into a variable), which looks like this:

> Sun Aug 28 19:31:16 +0000 2011

Into this:

> 19:31, Aug 28

But I need it to be timezone-aware. Any ideas about how to make this using `php`?

---

After using the second option which [John Flatness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331137/john-flatness) suggested I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Sao_Paulo' for 'BRT/-3.0/no DST' instead' in /misc.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /misc.php(4): DateTime->__construct('Sun Aug 28 19:3...')
#1 /tabs/home.php(29): format_date(Object(SimpleXMLElement), 'America/Sao_Pau...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /misc.php on line 4
```

Comment: You can pass the timezone as the second argument to the `DateTime` constructor to prevent that error (or set the date.timezone setting in php.ini or use `date_default_timezone_set` to explicitly set a default timezone).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you set the timezone you want to output in with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) (or the date.timezone INI setting), you can simply do:

```
$formatted_date = date('H:i, M d', strtotime('Sun Aug 28 19:31:16 +0000 2011'));
```

If you instead need to potentially output in many different time zones, it's probably easier to use the new-style [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime('Sun Aug 28 19:31:16 +0000 2011');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$formatted_date = $date->format('H:i, M d');
```

Obviously the `'America/New_York'` part would actually be a per-user setting for their timezone, not a literal string.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the timezone at the client?

Comment: I've added an alternative method that may be a better choice if you're going to be needing to output in many different timezones. As for detecting the user's timezone, that's really a different question, but as said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203382/how-to-automatically-detect-users-timezone, you can really only make a rough guess of your user's timezone. You're likely better off just asking them upfront and storing that information.