# Detect user timezone and display UTC time with that timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I have a table with UTC TIMESTAMPS column. How I display it with user timezone? Facebook uses user computer’s time settings. Facebook has no page for user setting their timezone, so I guest Facebook auto detect it. How I can achieve like Facebook? I'm using php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine a web user's time zone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically detect user's timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203382/how-to-automatically-detect-users-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably do this on the server side. You can instead detect the user's timezone using JavaScript but it may not be totally reliable.

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/