# How to get the physical server timezone offset (not from php.ini or IP)?

Tags: php, linux, datetime, timezone

How can one get the timezone **offset** of the *physical machine* sitting, not the timezone reported by php.ini (and certainly not through geoIP)?

From php.ini or in scripts we can easily set the default timezone. For example, on my box it's

[image: Timezone]]

In PHP,

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}
```

> date_default_timezone_set: Asia/Tokyo
>   date.timezone: Asia/Tokyo

However, the physical server is sitting in Mountain Time with the access logs having the timezone offset string -0700 in them.

---

**Solved:** Using `exec()` we can get system time and the current timezone **offset**. This is exactly what was needed. Thanks @codisfy for the inspiration.

```
echo shell_exec('date +\'%:z\'');
```

> -07:00

---

**Edit:** This question ([PHP 5.4 Can't Determine Time Zones on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747709/php-5-4-cant-determine-time-zones-on-its-own)) is about getting the timezone *name*, but of importance here is the timezone *offset*. Thanks for pointing out a possible duplicate, community, alas it is a different requirement.

Comment: At the OS level you can select time zone too, or the user level. I don't think there's a reliable way to get the time zone based on physical location, because there's not a reliable way to get location.

Comment: Can getting the time from system help you? something like this `print_r(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',(int)(shell_exec('date +%s'))));`

Comment: @codisfy Go for it. You saved me time and effort with your idea. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From comment to answer:*
You can get the system time using [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).
With which you can run a command as it would run on a shell and return you the output.

So doing something like this can help:

`shell_exec('date +\'%Z\'');`

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer.  `MST` is not a time zone identifier - it's an abbreviation.  Not all abbreviations are going to work as [tz identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), and [many are ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  For example, in the case of `MST`, is that `America/Denver` (which uses MST in the winter and MDT in the summer)? or is it `America/Phoenix` (which uses MST year-round)?  In the case of CST, that could be China Standard Time...

Comment: @MattJohnson You're right again. I ended up using `shell_exec('date +\'%:z\'');` to return the offset like `-07:00` to use that in log functions, parsed that and adjusted the TZ manually. Thanks for the spot.

Comment: That only tells you the *current* offset, which may not be the same for the date in question.  Time Zone != Offset.