# How to get client timezone in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am searching for PHP code which can get automatically timezone of client side. I had searched, and I found javascript who get timezone. How can I convert and use JavaScript in PHP to get timezone automatically?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_time_zone_offset( ) {
var current_date = new Date( );
var gmt_offset = current_date.getTimezoneOffset( ) / 60;
return gmt_offset;
}
$('#offset').html( get_time_zone_offset( ) );
</script>
```

Please help me to convert this code into PHP and call this function into echo.

I will be very thankful to you guys.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean. You just need to make sure that your PHP serves the appropriate Javascript as part of its HTML response... you *are* serving HTML from your PHP, right?

Comment: http://blog.codez.in/php5-time-zone-solution/web-development/2010/07/09 might help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203382/how-to-automatically-detect-users-timezone

Comment: i want to calculate timezone with the help of javascript and use this information in php and then show this with the help of echo.

Comment: @fazi if your end goal is to show it then why bother with php?

Comment: you r right but you know basically i am creating a php script which calculate prayer time and prayer time depend on sunrise and sunset so in euorope the time zone is +1 and -1h so now i want a code in php that calculate automatically timezone and set the dates automatically

Comment: Timezone != timezone offset

Comment: guys i will put my all the code here so you can see what i had done  and then i will explain that to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may send timezone_offset to the server via ajax. You may store it somewhere on the server then.
Or you may set a cookie with this value so it may be used on next page load.

But if you need to calculate and immedeately show it to the user - you better use javascript and maybe cookie for next page load.