# How can I do so that multiple users can access their current timezone instead of the one provided by my server using PHP

Tags: php

When I echo

`date_default_timezone_get()`

It echo's the server **datetime** instead of my current timezone. I wanted to have my real timezone.
How can I proceed with this.

Comment: The time zone from the client can not be determined with PHP. More:How to automatically detect user's timezone? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203382/how-to-automatically-detect-users-timezone

Comment: as facebook , use country to defined timezone , so easy you can delect time zone for each country and + or - it from time current time zone  and after all add the result to date time to that user :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your default zone with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

and get it:

```
$your_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
```

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) you can check supported timezones.

PS: When you know how to set timezone, you can get users browser timezone, [tutorial](http://usefulangle.com/post/31/detect-user-browser-timezone-name-in-php)  but you should use JS :)

Comment: If my answer helps you, you can upvote or mark it :)