# PHP timestamp and displaying correct date and time in different timezones

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp

I'm currently storing dates in my MYSQL database as a PHP timestamp (integer field).  However, if I retrieve it from the database and use the PHP date function, would it display the correct time based on the client's time zone.

For example, I display a PHP timestamp 1310674625 (pulled from DB) which is **Jul 14 2011 22:17:05** in Eastern Time.  So if I display the timestamp in PHP with the code below, would a person viewing the webpage in the Pacific Time Zone see **Jul 14 2011 19:17:05** instead?

```
echo date('M d Y H:i:s', 1310674625);
```

Comment: i dont think it will work like that, why dont u save it as UTC and use javascript to determine the client timezone and format it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The date will be displayed according to the server's time and timezone, not the user's.

You can offer an option on your site to allow the user provide his/her timezone (or attempt to use geolocation based on the IP) and adjust the output according.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863474/automatically-detect-users-current-local-time-with-javascript-or-php), reliably determining the user's timezone may not be possible, so for best results, you may need to get input from the user.

**EDIT** (Based on the request for more information in the comments)

If you need to output the selected timezone, you can use one of the following options:

```
echo date('e'); // Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores (Available in version 5.1.0 and later
echo date('O'); // Different in Greenwich meantime. Example: +0200
echo date('T'); // Timezone abbreviation. Examples: EST, MDT ...
```

See the [date](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php) manual page for more information.

**EDIT 2:**

To "print the date to a specified timezone" you will need to:

1. Get the current date as a timestamp (`time()`)
2. Get the user's timezone offset
3. Use mktime to add or subtract the user's offset as needed.
4. Convert the result back to human-readable format using `date()`.

Comment: @PeterBZ: Please see my updated answer for additional information.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) if you know users timezone

Also you can use Javascript Date(print timestamp here)

Comment: That will set the default timezone used by scripts on the server, but will not affect the data based on the location of the user.

Comment: You can ask user his timezone