# Automated date formatting based on browsers locale / location

Tags: php, javascript, date, locale

I am looking for solution in javascript or PHP which format "date" and "time" based on the visitors location and locale settings.

For example

```
echo auto_format_date(time());
```

would output 20-09-2011 for users from states and 20/09/2011 for UK users.

---

**Thanks everyone for answers. I've got now several alternatives in front of me, I'll wait for some up-votes to see which approach you think is preferred**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863474/automatically-detect-users-current-local-time-with-javascript-or-php

Comment: Let the user choose what they want - a person's geographic location doesn't necessarily indicate the format that they prefer.

Comment: Have you ever chosen locale on your mobile phone? User shouldn't bother with those things.

Comment: Think it should be month first in your example for US users, e.g. 09-20-2011 but i agree with RobG that whilst you can default the locale based on whatever info you can find from the browser agent, it's always best to allow the user to have the opportunity to override it in user preferences e.g. i have been in China for 18 months now and sometimes surf directly from the hotel internet connection but also have both UK and German VPN accounts for work. It would be annoying if everytime i went to a site, it changed all the locale settings because it decided i was a Chinese or German user.

Comment: Your locale settings would be the same though. You can change the setting, in your local Control Panel. That is, assuming javascript picks it up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another answer, which relies on [datejs](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

```
%x     preferred date representation for the current locale 
       without the time        "4/13/2008"
%X     preferred time representation for the current locale
       without the date        "12:53:05"
```

Answer (score 0):

In server side code (PHP, ASP.NET...) you can check `Accept-Language` HTTP header of request to detect client browser language.

Accept-Language: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4

You can read additional info: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Country from Ip by PHP Geolacator

and than use zned function: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

and when you create date:

$date = new Zend_Date();

echo $date;

You will get what you want...

Comment: how is it different form built-in date() and timezone functions?

Comment: also - relying on Geolocator would require me to update database of IP ranges which complicates installation and hosting requirements.

Comment: I use geoip to get country without IP ranges in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following myself:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp

which might help me format date into user's preferred format once it in the browser. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Date.toLocaleString() implemented but does not works as expected in WebKit browsers like Chrome,Safari.

Comment: I was also googling that. It seems that it's not broken, it is just different across all the browsers. It also looks rather long to be usable.

Comment: According with my knowledge, in Chrome (russian version) Date.toLocaleString() return string in english. And, Yes, toLocaleString() in IE,Opera,FireFox returns proper string (for locale) , but all has different result.