# Refresh Div at a certain time

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

Ok so I am creating a radio player and basically I need the Title, Content div, Next show Div to refresh at certain times for example 9am then 12pm. I have the JQuery code to refresh the page at a certain time but that isn't quite what I'm after. Any ideas?

Code:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date();

if(now.getHours() > hours ||
   (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
    now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
    then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
then.setHours(hours);
then.setMinutes(minutes);
then.setSeconds(seconds);

var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
```

Then I just call the refreshAt function by inserting the following on my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">refreshAt(04,30,0);</script> //page refreshes at 4:30am.
```

So this refreshes the Whole page. I just need to refresh the Title, and 2 divs.
What do I need to add/change in the code.

Comment: Whats your main logic behind refreshing the div are you trying to refresh to load some data inside div ?

Comment: Hello @Veerendra, The Logic behind it is say like a presenter is on air for example "John Smith - 09:00" when  the next presenter is on air at 12:00 I wish the div to change to "Peter Smith - 12:00" without the listener having to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will call your current URL after interval elapse and reset your `title` and your `div` content.

You have to write something like this:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
   var now = new Date();
   var then = new Date();

   if(now.getHours() > hours || (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) || now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >=  seconds) {
           then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
   }
   then.setHours(hours);
   then.setMinutes(minutes);
   then.setSeconds(seconds);

   var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
   setTimeout(function() {
      $.get( window.location.pathname, function( data ) {
             $('title') = $(data).filter('title').text();
             $('.DIV_CLASS') = $(data).filter('.DIV_CLASS').html();
             alert( "Load was performed." );
     });
   }, timeout);
}
```

**NOTE:** This script use jQuery, so please include latest jQuery library.

Comment: Is it possible to make it refresh the div with information from a list based on what time it is? So say like I have a list of people and each person had a time that they are on air. I would need the script to select a person based on what time it is and display it in the div. Do you know what I mean? Is it possible?

Comment: @user3011524 you mean to get user's system time and work according to it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean :)

Comment: @Julian Please go with this question: http://href=%27http://stackoverflow.com/a/863624/631652

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    document.title = "new title";
    $(".divname").text("new div text");
}, timeout);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, this is similar to what I am after but I wish to refresh at a certain time for example 12:00pm then refresh again at 15:0pm. The script must be able to get the time from the listeners computer so it know exactly when to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

By using is you can load the content of you div.

```
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $("#youfirstdivid").load("url1"); 
       $("#youseconddivid").load("url2");

      $('title').text("new title"); 
   }, timeout);
```

Don't forgot to wrap your code inside

```
$(function(){
  //you code goes here

});
```

and if you want to refresh it at some fixed interval then you can use setInterval rather than setTimeout

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't quite what I am after. I need to refresh those divs at certain times like 4pm then 8pm for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('#divid').load("pageurl #divid" >*",function(){

        });
  }, 6000);
```

Your div reload after 6 second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I am after.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking to do and mine too is for a radio station https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73784917/ajax-update-of-div-at-specific-hour-of-the-day I have a time interval as per the answers here but not yet worked out how to do it at a specific time eg. 2pm, 5pm.

Comment: I know you posted this 9 years ago but... if I solve this I'll update you!