# How to change the time zone according to client location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timezone

How to change the time zone to UTC to browser location. 
example time is 2014-01-01 10:10:10 (UTC)

I needed it depends upon the location (Browser depended)

Is its possible in PHP?
Or using Jquery.(JavaScript)

Comment: Do you need this Server-side or Client-side?

Comment: Check this link , it may help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863474/automatically-detect-users-current-local-time-with-javascript-or-php

Comment: you can set the required time zone in php and you can convert the dateTime in required timezone dateTime in Jquery and Javascript. first tell what do you want ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526897/634824

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
 echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Use this function to set timezone

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp

Check this url to timezones